# document.getElementById("").innerHTML doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I wanted to make a simple website that converts miles to KM, but it doesn't work. Why?

```
<form>
        <input type="text" name="miles" id="miles">
        <button type="submit" onclick="milesToKm();">CONVERT</button>
    </form>
<p id="result"></p>
<script>
        function milesToKm() {
            var miles = document.getElementById("miles").value;
            var km = miles * 1.60934;
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = km;

        }
</script>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `gEBI()` in your code. But, please tell me, what exactly you expect a submit button to do?

Comment: When you click on a submit button, it submits the form, which reloads the page. Change it to `type="button"`.

Comment: Or get rid of `<form>`

Answer (score 2):

Your button has `type="submit"`. Pressing that button calls execution of your script, but the page gets immediately reloaded. Remove `type="submit"`.

As an example: http://codepen.io/pitetsky/pen/XNoyEW

Answer (score 1):

You put type = submit so after click on this page is reload and your data is destroyed due to this you unable to see the changes.
here is your working code:

```
<form>
        <input type="text" name="miles" id="miles">
        <button type="button" onclick="milesToKm()">CONVERT</button>
    </form>
<p  id="result"></p>
<script>
function milesToKm() {
            var miles = document.getElementById("miles").value;
            var km = miles * 1.60934;
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = km;

        }
</script>
```